# Installation of cuDNN with VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, deep-learning, nvidia, cudnn

I am trying to install cuDNN in Widows 10 by following the documentation Installation Guide - NVIDIA Docs.

But I am stuck in the step of cuDNN to your Visual Studio project: changing the Solution Explorer properties. Because I am working on VS code, and this is only available in Visual Studio.

Is possible to work with VScode, or should I start working Visual Studio?

I think it might work if I create a CMake project extensions, but I am not really sure it works.

Comment: Installing CUDNN is only copying two files, the library and the header. All you need to do is tell your compiler/IDE where to find the header during compilation and where to find the library during linking.